# The probability of breaking symmetric encryptions

Tags: encryption

The probabilty of cracking AES is $1 \over 2^n$, n being the size of the key. Would this hold true for every encryption of the same size?

This is from RC4's Wikipedia page:

> In March 2015 researcher to Royal Holloway announced [improvements](http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/tls/RC4mustdie.html) to their attack, providing a $2^{26}$ attack against passwords encrypted with RC4, as used in TLS.

This might answer my question, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Technically the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) is a symmetric encryption algorithm and it is broken so easily it barely requires pen & paper.

So no, this does not hold.

Also, I'm not sure where you got that figure but that is the probability of guessing the correct key in one attempt. Given a modern computer it should at least be feasible to attempt two guesses. ;)

Comment: Addendum: the security strength in bits of an algorithm is basically set to the number of operations required for the best attack mechanism available.  For AES this is only slightly lower than the key size. Keep in mind that these kind of figures are only the accumulation of all the crypt-analysis performed on the cipher. The real world is - as always - more complex than that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So what is the current value for AES?

Comment: [About 2 bits less than the actual bit values.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Known_attacks)